# TypeOrm - Can't create a connection outside of main function

Tags: sqlite, electron, typeorm

I have a problem with typeorm, function createConnection  works only in index file, if I try to run it in any other file it gets stuck waiting for connection.

```js
export async function saveKU(data: KUData) {
    console.log("Foo");
    let connection = await createConnection(typeormConfig);
    console.log("Received!: " + connection);
    const user = connection
        .getRepository(KU)
        .createQueryBuilder("ku")
        .where("ku.ku_number = :ku_number", { ku_number: "54645" })
        .getOne();

    console.log(user);
}
```

Message received never gets logged, but then if I run the exact same script in the main function

```js
const main = async () => {
  // quit application when all windows are closed
  app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    // on macOS it is common for applications to stay open until the user explicitly quits
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  app.on("activate", () => {
    // on macOS it is common to re-create a window even after all windows have been closed
    if (mainWindow === null) {
      mainWindow = createMainWindow();
    }
  });

  app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true;
  // create main BrowserWindow when electron is ready
  app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow();
  });

  let connection = await createConnection(typeormConfig);
  console.log("Received!: " + connection);
  const user = connection
    .getRepository(KU)
    .createQueryBuilder("ku")
    .where("ku.ku_number = :ku_number", { ku_number: "54645" })
    .getOne();

  console.log(user);
};
```

Everything works fine, no error is showing up in both cases, I have no idea what the problem could be, the closest to my example is the following link: https://senorihl.github.io/2019/03/electron-typescript-react-typeorm/
Except that I'm using electron-webpack and creating connections in an index.tsx file doesn't work for me, but rather index.ts